# Android Request Codes pattern in startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Whenever I design an Android Activity that is called with `startActivityForResult` I always find myself blurting out any number than comes to mind and using it as the request code.

Is there a specified pattern or numbering scheme I should follow for these request codes?

*(ps: Should I move this to a different Stack Exchange page?)*

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you, I use this pattern, example:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO = 1;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_CROPPER = 2;

    //code
}
```